# intellej idea. как запустить написанную в среде программу через терминал. Не могу найти свой мейн класс для запуска

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В папке out есть все классы, но нет моего основного. Вместо него есть Main но я не могу его запустить через терминал. Объясните. P.S. я новичок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы запустить файл вашей программы из командной строки нужно выполнить такие шаги:

1. Перейти в папку вашего проекта, например она выглядит так `C:\mywork`:

   ```
   C:\> cd \mywork
   ```

   Это сделает папку проекта текущей папкой.
2. Написать такую команду:

   ```
   C:\mywork> dir
   ```

   Это покажет файл в папке вашего проекта. Там должен находится и ваш файл классаю
3. Укажите системе где искать JDK:

   ```
   C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin
   ```
4. Проведите запуск файла `javac.exe`, что является компилятором:

   ```
   C:\mywork> javac HelloWorld.java
   ```
5. Выведите список файлов снова:

   ```
   C:\mywork> dir
   ```
6. Запустите вашу программу:

   ```
   C:\mywork> java HelloWorld
   ```

[Первоисточник](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) и вот [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows). Удачи :)

Comment: Возможно я неправильно задал вопрос. Я несколько месяцев работал с терминалом и запускал программы через него. Проблема в том что создав проект в IDEA, она создает много папок для исходных файлов и компилированных. И создает файл майн( вроде вход в проект) но исчез мой основной класс майн( Я так пониаю IDEA заменила его название на Main) из-за этого я просто не могу запустить программу с терминала( нужен Main class с таким же названием как и файл а его нет). Есть ли способ запустить все это через терминал или консоль?

Comment: а в чем проблема запустить проект через idea? там одна кнопка и все)

Comment: вот-вот, запусти из среды и увидь какой длинный там строка запуска, сразу перехочется ручками это каждый раз набирать